# Is there a setting within the package "qualtRics" that removes the unnecessary portions of column names?

Tags: r, survey, qualtrics

When reading in survey data from Qualtrics to R, block titles attach themselves to variable names/import tags. All I want is the import tags/variable names originally in Qualtrics.

Here is my code:

```
data <- fetch_survey(surveyID = "sdfajksjsl", label  = F, convert = F, force_request = T)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the parameter ```import_id```? Can't try it for you because one has to register an API to get the survey data.

Comment: Can you share an example of the variable names you're seeing?  When I've used fetch_survey() to retrieve results from a survey with blocks, I don't have this problem.  You might want to check whether the variable names have been altered within Qualtrics itself using the Recode Values facility?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Qualtrics API key, so can't check this, but looks like it should get you the tags in the original file.

```
library(qualtRics)
data <- fetch_survey(surveyID = "sdfajksjsl", 
                     label  = F, 
                     convert = F, 
                     force_request = T,
                     import_id = TRUE)
```

From the help file for fetch_survey:
import_id   Logical. If TRUE, use Qualtrics import IDs instead of question IDs as column names. Defaults to FALSE.

Comment: @blaze does this fix your problem?  If so, please upvote and accept the answer.  If not, I may have an alternative solution, but will need more info about what your data looks like.